What is Islam Stack Exchange’s policy on using AI-generated content in answers?
Stack Overflow has prohibited the use of generative AI tools (like GPT) to create answers, requiring all content to be original or a properly referenced summary of others’ work.
As Stack Overflow policy is :

Generative artificial intelligence (a.k.a. GPT, LLM, generative AI, genAI) tools may not be used to generate content for Stack Overflow. The content you provide must either be your own original work, or your summary of the properly referenced work of others. If your content is determined to have been written by generative artificial intelligence tools, it will likely be deleted, along with any reputation earned from it. Posting content generated by generative artificial intelligence tools may lead to a warning from moderators, or possibly a suspension for repeated infractions.

This policy highlights concerns about accuracy, ownership, and the potential for misleading information generated by AI.
Given the specialized nature of Islam Stack Exchange, where accuracy and authenticity are critical, does Islam Stack Exchange have a similar policy regarding AI-generated content? If not, are there specific guidelines or considerations that the community or moderators recommend for using AI to assist in formulating answers?

I hate that this is even a question.
I have spent a long time trying to keep Islam.SE viable, and one of the biggest drivers for that is the sheer ignorance that runs rampant in the Islamic community, at least among English speakers. Not just from people without knowledge who regurgitate whatever they read on social media or blogs, including straight-up misinformation, but there's a very strong trend that actively discourages people from developing the basic critical skills required to actually learn and understand Islamic principles.
Despite the fact that Stack Exchange is marketed as a Q&A site, we're not really here to answer questions, that's just a means to an end: We're here to build a repository of Islamic knowledge, a library for future reference. When people ask questions, honest questions seeking knowledge that they cannot find elsewhere, that demonstrates what knowledge needs to be developed, and answering those questions is how we build that library.
Posting and re-posting the same articles and blog posts and fatawa over and over again for the same oft-repeated questions — which is the predominant form of discourse on way too many Islamic sites — does not build knowledge. It just repeats what is already known, or can already easily be found elsewhere, often for those who lack the basic skills to find it themselves. There is little to no long-term value in that, and perpetuating it is a never-ending cycle of new users who haven't learned — or never try to learn — the basic skills and knowledge needed to go beyond the same questions year after year after year.
This is why we take such a strong stance against copy-paste: If regurgitating the same information over and over again was ever going to work, it's had countless years to prove itself, but I'm still seeing the same tired questions over and over and over again that I saw back when I was still in high school (which, for those keeping score, was over three decades ago). We need to be different. We need to be better.
We need to be bringing something new into the equation. That requires people with actual expertise, with knowledge beyond the shallow oft-repeated and unsatisfying answers that are already prevalent. This requires people with the critical skills to understand what they're saying, who can explain it to others, who can clarify and focus knowledge in a manner that can be useful to people who lack those skills, the people who come to us for help. That's what we bring to the table that other sites do not. That's what we aspire to do.
That's how we build a comprehensive library that's useful for not only us, but all future visitors.

But let's get back to the question at hand: What should we do about Generative AI?
Generative AI… doesn't develop knowledge. It never has. It is an incredibly sophisticated model trained on contextual information that is already available, and it simulates English language in a way that makes it sound knowledgeable, but it doesn't understand what it's saying at all.
Generative AI has its uses. If used by educated people who know its limitations and are able to recognize its errors, it can be powerful. But using it as a replacement for actual education and expertise is just irresponsible. It's nothing but a glorified regurgitator, basically taking the worst of everything I described above and packaging it all into one convenient prompt.
The fact that people care so little about their own religion that they are willing to trust machines, machines that understand the topic even less than the least educated layman, machines which have a history of hallucinating and spreading straight-up lies, machines which will never be held accountable for their own mistakes, the fact that anyone is willing to trust these machines to provide a helpful answer is just depressing.
The fact that they have so little respect for Islam that they're also willing to spread answers written by these machines as if that's even remotely comparable to something written by someone actually educated in Islamic principles is deplorable.
The purpose of this site is to increase the base of Islamic knowledge available to everybody, and we're never going to accomplish that if we just keep repeating what's already easily available, which is really the only thing that generative AI does well (and barely even that). The rewards here are minimal, and the risk of rewarding ignorant people for spreading misinformation is way too high: I don't see how it has any place here.
